# How can I create a login page for two different domains with one user pool

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have two different domains [www.domaina.com](http://www.domaina.com) and [www.domainb.com](http://www.domainb.com), I want to have one login page for both of the domains, for authentication I am using aws Cognito service.
What steps do I need to take in order to achieve that?